# Partial View, User Control, or something else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controls

I've been developing console, service and Windows forms apps for many years in C#, and have only just started dabbling in web development and MVC, and I'm hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction to achieve what I want to do.

The project I'm working on, involves porting in an house legacy PHP based timesheet system over to a C# ASP MVC 4 application.

The main purpose of the system is to provide users with a way of booking working hours against projects, with rows containing project & tasks, and a column for each day of the week, and a total in the last column and row, something like this:

```
            mon   tue   wed   thu   fri   sat   sun   total

Project 1   0:00  1:00  0:00  2:00  0:00  0:00  0:00   3:00
Project 2   0:30  0:00  5:00  0:00  0:00  0:00  0:00   5:30
Project 3   0:00  0:00  0:00  4:00  5:00  0:00  0:00   9:00

Total       0:30  1:00  5:00  6:00  5:00  0:00  0:00  17:30
```

I believe in writing good, clean, readable code, and I want to minimise the amount of code added into a view, so I don't want to develop a horrible mess of nested loops within a single view. What I'm looking to do is break each component into manageable chunks, for example, I make the entire view into an entity in its own right, then use another nested entity for each project row.

From the research I've done, it looks like either an `MVC 4 View User Control` or a `Partial View` might what I'm looking for, but I can't find a good description of what each of these items are actually designed to do.

Ideally, I'd want to be able to pass one or more objects into the control/view so that the code within it can build the output based upon the objects passed in.

What's the best way of achieving this? User Control, Partial View or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can tell User Controls are in the old ASP.NET Web Pages and the equivalent in MVC are Partial views.

A partial view is a view which you can include in a regular view. For example if you have a site which will display comments on a couple of different pages. Say, the user can view his own comment history on one page and the user can also view comments under news or blog articles on another part of the site. You could make the comments a partial view which is then included in both the articles and the users comment history. Then if you need to make changes to the comment view it will be updated in both places.

You can also pass models into partial views. For example, using the example i provided above. Lets say i have a article with a collection of comments attached to it as such:

```
public class ArticleModel 
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class CommentModel 
{
     public string Body { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Now one way to display these comments under an article using a partial view would be like this:

```
@model Application.ArticleModel

<div>
    <h2>@Model.Title</h2>
    <article>@Model.Body</article>

    @foreach(var comment in Model.Comments) 
    {
        @Html.RenderPartial("_CommentPartial", comment)
    }
</div>
```

And here's what that partial view could look like:

```
@model Application.CommentModel
<div>
    <p>@Model.Body</p>
    <span>Written by @Model.UserName</span>
</div>
```

With this the article view is a lot cleaner and you can use the partial view in other places as well. Another way to do it would be to pass the comment collection into the partial view and then put the foreach loop into it as well.

There are a lot explanations online which are way better but i hope i could be of some use.

Comment: Many thanks. After reading your answer, I focused on partial views and found the following interesting article, [What is a partial view and when should I use it?](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/). Hopefully that will be of use to others who read this.